# Error: data.map is not a function. This error throws whenever I run react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I am running HorizontallScrollbar component by passing data as a prop. Whenever I run HorizontalScrollbar component then following error coming in console tab of Chrome:

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

**HorizontalScrollbar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Box} from '@mui/material';

const HorizontalScrollbar = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <div> 
           {data.map((item) => ( 
            <Box 
            key = {item.id || item}
            itemId = {item.id || item}
            title = {item.id || item}
            m = "0 40px"
            >
            {item}
            </Box>
            )
        )
            
    }
        </div>
)
}

export default HorizontalScrollbar;
```

**Passing data as a Prop:**

```
 <Box sx = {{position: "relative", width: "100%", p: "20px"}}>
     <HorizontalScrollbar data = {bodyParts} />
     </Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `bodyParts` instantiated? Is it a state? If it is it should default to an empty array `[]`

Or you could add a check before mapping through. I added an [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)  check before invoking the `map()` function as it is only for Arrays.

**Additional Info**

It could be that `data` is not yet populated due to waiting for an API call to complete or some other reason. In this case my fix would simply render an empty div during first render due to the check and prevent the console error. During next render when the data is ready the data in this case would be a proper Array type, the check would pass (`Array.isArray(data)`) and the items would render the `Box` component properly.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Box} from '@mui/material';

const HorizontalScrollbar = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <div> 
           {Array.isArray(data) && data.map((item) => ( 
            <Box 
            key = {item.id || item}
            itemId = {item.id || item}
            title = {item.id || item}
            m = "0 40px"
            >
            {item}
            </Box>
            )
        )
            
    }
        </div>
)
}

export default HorizontalScrollbar;
```

Comment: My code runs. Thanks Mohd Yashim Wong. Can you please explain. How you fixed this in detail. That would be appreciated.

Comment: I added some explanation. Hopefully it makes sense @SalmanDalal

Answer (score 0):

I think using the double ampersand && gives it an option.

That is, if API had not been called, remain empty for the time being